# Is google load balancer awaking sleeping instances?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am planing to migrate to gcp and my front needs some level of reliability, but I am also cost constrained and cannot offer to double my instances.

Is it possible to have one running instance with a load balancer which test its health, and in case of failure would awake a sleeping copy of this instance ?

That would provide a kind of automatic fail-over with an interruption of service of 1 to 2 minutes, which is acceptable for my business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) with autoscaling (minNumReplicas=1, maxNumReplicas=1) and autohealing. Managed Instance Groups can automatically identify and recreate unhealthy instances.

You can apply [HTTP health checks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups) to Managed Instance Groups to monitor and verify that servers are running properly on the instances in that group. If a health check determines that a service has failed on an instance, the group automatically recreates that instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there the same kind of mechanism for Cloud SQL, like automatised restart or backup restore... the HA is out of our budget but a few mins downtime is acceptable

Comment: Cloud SQL is different because it's a managed service. Assuming that you don't choose HA, then Cloud SQL will be running on a single instance in a single zone. Because it's a managed service, Google will be responsible for keeping the service up, to the extent that it can. During a zonal outage, it is likely to be down, of course, and how long that situation persists is not very predictable. It could be minutes, hours, or even potentially days though the latter is highly unlikely.